# How to decorate formDirective in angular to set autocomplete off?

Tags: angularjs, forms, autocomplete, decorator, directive

I was looking for a general solution to set all form fields' `autocomplete` to `off`, 
I came up with this solution:

```
 var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

    app.directive('form', function() {
      return function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        elem.attr('autocomplete', 'off');
      }
    });
```

and since when angular applies directives with same names in an array like fashion , it is guaranteed that for every form element `autocomplete` is set to off.

I was wondering this approach is better or using `decorator`(or How to do it with `decorator`)?

Comment: Actually you can use [app.config] to handle that by using [provider], but why? because in this sample you use directives to handle the public problem and you have t set your directive to all forms, but with config/run/provider you can create a public solution for all your forms.

Comment: the point is that by using this directive I don't need to set it anywhere! it is already applied wherever I have a form. I was looking what `decorator` solution would look like.

Comment: So it's great and good job :)